# Using the Formula SUMIF() and WHEN() in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I tried a Formula in Excel for the following condition. In the first line I have the month from January to March. All the values which are corresponding to the months are in the second line. I want to sum up these values. For example the values from month January would be 30.

I got it figured out up to this formula: `=WENN(A1:J1;SUMMEWENN(A1:J1;MONAT(1);A2:J2))` . I am searching in the entire row for the month 1 ( January ) but when I copy this for `Feb` it does not work I  get the same result. By the way it is the German version :-)

[image: Table]

thx all.

Comment: What is your top row formatted as, "text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your top row is formatted as text. If that is the case then this might be a possible solution for you:

For January:  `=SUMMEWENN($A$1:$J$1,"01",$A$1:$J$1)`  which would yield 30
For Feb:  `=SUMMEWENN($A$1:$J$1,"02",$A$1:$J$1)`  which would yield 17
For March:  `=SUMMEWENN($A$1:$J$1,"03",$A$1:$J$1)`  which would yield 26

Let me know if something is unclear.

EDIT:
This second portion might be easier because you can put it in cell A5 then drag it down to cell A7.

`=SUMMEWENN($A$1:$J$1,MONAT(DATWERT(A5&"1")),$A$1:$J$1)`

Comment: Pleasure, glad I could be of help.

Comment: One question, but the month "01" "02" I always have to change per hand, right? or can I use there something like $1 :D?

Comment: @flowers1234 you can put value of the month in another cell then fill down

Comment: Yes, you can also just use the number or you could do this: ```=SUMMEWENN($A$1:$J$1,MONAT(DATWERT(A5&"1")),$A$1:$J$1)``` then drag it down for all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to freeze the range "A1:J1". Use the below Code

```
=WENN($A$1:$J$1;SUMMEWENN($A$1:$J$1;MONAT(1);$A$2:$J$2))
```